# Flutter Shared Preference

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

So I've created a login page for flutter through MySQL and now I'm adding to it shared preferences to keep the user logged in. My first step was saving username, password, and token and the second step was of course getting username and password. Both steps work fine, but the third step should be navigating to the next page(User) while also pushing id and phone. While it is navigating to the next page but the page is empty.. I think its because it's not pushing id and phone to the next page.

```
     savePref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('username', username);
    prefs.setString('password', password);
    prefs.setString('token', mytoken);
  }

  getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    user = prefs.getString('username');
    pass = prefs.getString('password');

   

     if (user != null) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => User(
                        id: id,
                        phone: phone,
                      )));
        } else {
          print('Login');
        }
      }
```

this is source code to create a multiple login flutter using backend PHP and MySQL

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// import http.dart plugin that was previously entered into pubspec.yaml
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:multiple_login/admin.dart';
import 'package:multiple_login/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

var fbm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
var mytoken;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Multiple Login Flutter",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: Login(),
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  // variable for saving data from data json which derive from php code in the file login.php
  String username, password, status, id, phone, user, pass;

  String alert = "asd";

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController usernameInput = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordInput = new TextEditingController();

  savePref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('username', username);
    prefs.setString('password', password);
    prefs.setString('token', mytoken);
  }

  getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    user = prefs.getString('username');
    pass = prefs.getString('password');

      if (user != null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => User(
                    id: id,
                    phone: phone,
                  )));
    } else {
      print('Login');
    }
  }




  @override
  void initState() {
    fbm.getToken().then((token) {
      setState(() {
        mytoken = token;
      });
    });
    getPref();
    super.initState();
  }


  
  // method for login process
  void loginProcess() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // 10.0.2.2 is ip address from android studio's emulator

      final response = await http.post(
          "http://***",
          body: {
            "username": usernameInput.text,
            "password": passwordInput.text,
            "token": mytoken
          });

      var dataUser = json.decode(response.body);

      if (dataUser.length < 1) {
        // if data user is empty or 0
        setState(() {
          alert = "Username or Password incorrect";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          username = dataUser[0]["email"];
          password = dataUser[0]["password"];
          status = dataUser[0]["level"];
          id = dataUser[0]["stid"];
          phone = dataUser[0]["phone"];
        });

        // move the page according to user status
        if (status == "1") {
          // use navigator push replacement so that user can not go back to login page
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Admin(
                        username: username,
                      )));
        } else {
          savePref();
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => User(
                        id: id,
                        phone: phone,
                      )));
        }
      }

    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.blue[900].withOpacity(0.0),
    ));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(""),
            Text(""),
            Text(""),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black87, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.asset('asset/CHS.png'),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  "asd",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black87),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  alert,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: usernameInput,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87)),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.mail,
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter your username",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                          labelText: "Username",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                        ),
                        validator: (String value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return "Username is empty";
                          }

                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: passwordInput,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87)),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter your password",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                          labelText: "Password",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                        ),
                        validator: (String value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return "Password is empty";
                          }

                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        elevation: 5,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.white,
                            onTap: () {
                              loginProcess();
                            },
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Login",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `id` and `phone` coming from?

Comment: From mysql.. I posted the full code

Comment: You call `getPref` from `initState`, but `id` and `phone` don't get set anywhere other than `loginProcess` which doesn't run unless the user taps a button. By the time you are trying to nagivate, `id` and `phone` haven't been set.

Comment: @Abion47 Bro you're amazing, now it's working just fine. Thank you.